# iOS image file names for iPad Air 2 and iPad Pro

Tags: ios, image, ipad, size, retina

In [“iOS Human Interface Guidelines”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2) say what images sizes for iPads is:

iPad Air 2 - [1536 x 2048] = @2x
iPad Pro – [2048 x 2732] = @2x

I use such name convention for retina iPad Air 2 [1536 x 2048]:

Background@2x~ipad.png

But which of name must assign for iPad Pro – [2048 x 2732]?

Comment: Are you talking about launch images or are you referring to other images?

Comment: rmaddy>  Images what uses as background for application, or background for other user interface elements, which I load on maner: UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];

Comment: The HIG you referenced doesn't cover such images. And there is no standard naming convention for such images. And `UIImage imageNamed:` doesn't easily support such images. You are on your own for naming and loading such images.

Comment: rmaddy> I am beginner in iOS development and you more confused me ;) In Resource Programming Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) say what I can use prefix like '@2x' or '~ipad' for assign special image for special devices.

Comment: rmaddy> Other good article about size and file names convention: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/sizes-and-filenames/ or I misunderstand?

Comment: So the recommendation is then to us a separate storyboard for iPad vs iPad Pro.  I use a common storyboard for iphone and ipad and use layout constraints and image naming conventions such as Background@2x~ipad.png to let iOS auto determine which image to load based on the image name.  It sounds like there is no special naming convention for iPad Pro images and I am forced to manually swap out the images myself based on device?  I used to be able to just drop four files in code image.png, image@2x.png, image~ipad.png and image@2x~ipad.png and iOS chose the correct file for me based on device.

Comment: Stinger> Yes using different image sizes (2x~ipad) and layouts is convenient but standard UIImage for now not support many other Device resolutions (as I know), so you need write self library for support all Apple device resolutions. Such as Background@3x~ipad.png and Background@3x~iphone.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it https://github.com/kevindelord/UIImage-Autoresize tries to solve this. Haven't tried it myself yet though.